# combobox width fit to viewbox container

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want my combobox width fit to it's viewbox container.

```
<Viewbox StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="5,5,5,5">
  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding item}"/>
</Viewbox>
```

The combobox take width of selected item.

Comment: You want to *scale* combobox and at the same time resize it to occupy available width? It's kind of hard to imagine. Got a screenshot of how it would looks like? Using other container (e.g. a `Grid`) would allow you either to stretch as usual or bind `Width` to `ActualWidth` of parent. Why `ViewBox`?

Comment: yes I use the viewbox for the resize of my control when window's size is not the design size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Change `Stretch` mode to `Fill` instead of `Uniform`.

Output:
[image]

Comment: Produces grafic bugs, at least when I try it with the IErrorDataInfo Interface Implementation